# Function whose derivative is between 0 and 1, and its image set.

Tags: real-analysis

Let us say there is a function $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ such that it's derivative is  between $0$ and $1$, for any $x\in[a,b]$, and that the equation $x=f(x)$ only has one solution in $[a,b]$. Does this imply that $f$ maps $[a,b]$ to $[a,b]$, and, if so, how does one prove it.

Comment: Since $f' = (f+C)'$ for any constant $C$, the values of the derivative cannot tell you anything about the values of $f$. The derivative controls the "shape" of the function, but not its values.

Answer (score 2):

The derivative of $f$ controls the shape, but not the specific values, of the function. If $c$ is a constant, and $g(x) = f(x)+c$, then $g'=f'$, but $g$ is a vertical shift of $f$. So even if $f$ happened to take values in $[a,b]$, then a vertical shift would not, yet it would have the same derivative. So you have no hope of having this be true as stated.

On the other hand, the Mean Value Theorem *can* tell you something about $f(b)-f(a)$. Namely, the mean value theorem tells you that there exists a point $c$, $a\lt c\lt b$, such that
$$ f'(c) = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}.$$
Given that $0\leq f'(c)\leq 1$, that tells you that
$$0 \leq \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} \leq 1$$
or that
$$0\leq f(b)-f(a) \leq b-a.$$

That means that if $f(b) \leq f(a) + (b-a)$. So $f$ maps $[a,b]$ into $[f(a),f(a)+b-a]$.

Answer (score 0):

The function $f(x)=300+\frac 1 2 x $ has derivative $f'(x)=\frac 1 2$ which lies between 0 and 1, but $f(x)$ maps $[0,1]$ to $[300,301]$ which is not $[0,1]$.